# 50s Young adult book about aliens from Venus who came to Earth and ignored children

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

My husband clearly remembers an odd book from the fifties that was science fiction but was treated as fact. It came from a school library so it should have had a well known or at least a good author. It featured aliens who had come from Venus to Earth. The aliens interacted with humans but NOT children. It was told as a story that had really happened although obviously it had not.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question is quite terse and would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)